# Cannot upgrade from AGP version 7.2.1 to version 8.1.2

Tags: gradle, build.gradle, upgrade

Why is it that when I use use AGP upgrade assistant to upgrade my AGP from 7.2.1 to 8.1.2 it says target AGP version unsupported

But if I try any gradle version that start with 7. It will say AGP version is unverified.
This is the error I was getting "could not install gradle distribution from 'https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-8.1-bin.zip'.